# add VML elements (images) with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, element, hidden, vml

hi I've been trying to add VML image elements using javascript.
now here is what I'm using to generate these images:

```
function add_tools()
{       
var elemm = document.createElement('rvml:image'); 
elemm.setAttribute('src', 'pic.png');
elemm.setAttribute('id', 'gogo');
elemm.setAttribute('class', 'rvml');
document.body.appendChild(elemm);   

document.getElementById('gogo').style.position='absolute';
document.getElementById('gogo').style.width=55;
document.getElementById('gogo').style.height=55;
document.getElementById('gogo').style.top=200;
document.getElementById('gogo').style.left=300;
document.getElementById('gogo').style.rotation=200;
document.getElementById('gogo').style.display = "block"; 
}
```

usually when I generate vml image element the HTML code should look somthing like:

```
<rvml:image style="POSITION:absolute; WIDTH:55px; HEIGHT:55px; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; rotation:0;" src="pic.png" id=gogo class=rvml>
```

now the above javascript function works with HTML elements. 
but when I use it to generate VML elements. the generated element doesn't show in the browser. but when I check document.body.innerHTML. I can see that the element has been actually created. but its not showing..

any ideas?
is there any method I can use to refresh or redraw elements with javascript. or anything I can use to fix this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uh. fixed it myself as usual...

```
function add_tools()
{   
var elemm = document.createElement('rvml:image'); 
elemm.src = 'pic.png';
elemm.className = 'rvml';
document.body.appendChild(elemm);
elemm.id = "gogo";
elemm.style.position='absolute';
elemm.style.width=55;
elemm.style.height=55;
elemm.style.top=200;
elemm.style.left=300;
elemm.style.rotation=200; 
}
```

it seems like the setAttribute function is not changing the status of the element.
but still I'm having problem with events. now if I want to use:

```
elemm.onload = "alert('coco')";
```

this should be triggered when I run the javascript function which will draw the element.
but I'm not getting that alert box to be workin. hmm its kindda weird. I checked the innerHTML i can see it right there.

Comment: For future reference on this, there is a library called dd_roundies that creates VML elements with javascript in order to create rounded corners. The way Drew Diller does this is quite good I think, except you can't undo or remove the VML it creates. http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

Answer (score 2):

I struggled endlessly with this, and in the end I used a fill instead:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <vml:rect stroked="f" style="position:absolute"> 
    <vml:fill type="tile" aspect="ignore" src="pathto.png" style="position:absolute">  
    </vml:fill>
  <vml:rect> 
</div>
```

It seems that position absolute is required, hence the need for a position relative containing div.

For more info check out the superpng plug-in for jQuery which uses this technique for png alpha replacement.

Comment: Thanks. `fill` indeed works better than `image`; there at least the shape reacts to transformations (the image itself does not, for that you need SVG).